# RHEL + how to download rpms from RHEL 8.x repos when using RHEL machine 7.x

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

we are using the server RHEL 7.9 version for downloading rpm's from 7.x line

we connected to rhel 7.x repositories , as the following ( VIA subscription-manager )

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
repo id                                                                                                     repo name                                                                                                            status
docker-ce-stable/7Server/x86_64                                                                             Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                                     245
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64                                                                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)                                                                           1,457
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)                                                                  18,552+5,311
rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                             26,611+7,114
repolist: 46,865
```

so far, we are downloading rpm's from rhel repo and that's fine.

the question now what in case we want to download rpm's from 8.x RHEL repositories.

can we use the same RHEL 7.9 in order to download rpm's from 8.x repos ?

here is example to what we did.

we add the additional relevant repos for rhel 8.x as the following example

```
vi redhat.repo


[rhel-8-for-x86_64-highavailability-rpms]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - High Availability (RPMs)
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/$releasever/x86_64/highavailability/os
enabled = 0
gpgcheck = 1
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify = 1
sslcacert = /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/8663009972005896744-key.pem
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/8663009972005896744.pem
metadata_expire = 86400
enable_metadata = 0
ui_repoid_vars = releasever
```

and we did the following additional steps

```
yum clean all
subscription-manager refresh
```

and

```
yum repolist
```

but we still get only the repo for 7.x

```
repo id                                                                                                     repo name                                                                                                            status
docker-ce-stable/7Server/x86_64                                                                             Docker CE Stable - x86_64                                                                                                     245
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64                                                                            Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Extras (RPMs)                                                                           1,457
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Optional (RPMs)                                                                  18,552+5,311
rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64                                                                           Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server (RPMs)                                                                             26,611+7,114
repolist: 46,865
```

what is wrong with our process?

reference -
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4547301
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/329373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum`'s `--releasever=` flag is your friend.

However, there's (as far as I can tell) no guarantees for forward compatibility of old `yum` versions with new repo layouts. It makes much more sense to use the *recent* OS to download *old* packages, than vice versa.